# Raspberry Pi Losing Power

Tags: power

I bought a Raspberry Pi that had the entire n64 library loaded onto it. it takes an HDMI cable to plug into the TV and has a regular USB to micro USB for the power. I start it up and it begins to boot but along the way it just loses power. I have tried many different power bricks to rectify the situation, most rated at 2.4A, but it keeps dropping power. is there another power brick i can use that will maintain power?

Comment: `is there another power brick i can use that will maintain power` - yes, a quality one that is rated to deliver the requirements of your Raspberry Pi  (you haven't mentioned which model you have - there are at least 10 different ones I can think of off the top of my head) - I gather "loses power" means that you get the voltage warning icon on your screen, not that the pi just switches off

Comment: the Pi is in a 3d printed case and i didn't want to break it opening it up to check the model. i just ordered a power supply that will hopefully do the trick. but there is no voltage or error warning, it just switches off.

Comment: right ... you can get the model of the pi without physically inspecting it using many methods - the easiest is by `cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model` (assuming you have power long enough)

Comment: if it "just switches off", then there's something electrically wrong with it though. What USb peripherals are connected to the pi (I'm assuming keyboard and mouse at least)

Comment: USB keyboard and controller. i also have different lengths of time depending on the power brick i am using. so far it runs the longest with an apple one for some reason. i'll see if the new power supply i ordered doesn't work then see if i can dig deeper into what is wrong. thank you for your help.

Comment: quick question. If you power up the pi and do absolutely nothing, does it just power off? Or is it during use (I take it n64 is something to do with gaming)?